# Geonetwork startup error: bootstrap.less wasn't found

Tags: tomcat, geonetwork

I am running geonetwork 3.0 on ubuntu 14.04. Since I restarted my tomcat the last time I get the weird error when calling geonetwork:

> FileError:
>   'geonetwork/catalog/lib/style/bootstrap-3.0.1/bootstrap.less' wasn't
>   found (404)

in connection with the stacktrace message

```
OperationAbortedEx : Failed whilst adding the schema information. Exception message if any is /tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/
data/resources/xml/schemas/iso19139/schema/gmd/metadataEntity.xsd
...
...
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/data/resources/xml/schemas/iso19139/schema/gmd/metadataEntity.xsd
```

I had a look and bootstrap.less actually exists, but it lives under

> style/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less

Any ideas what to do against this weird error? I don't know how to fix an AccessDeniedException on the mentioned xsd file. Actually tomcat should be able to access, if he's able to deploy?!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't cange anything? Privileges over the files? Are you using an external data directory? If you are, you can remove safely the geonetwork folder inside webapps and let Tomcat redeploy.

Comment: I am quite sure, I didn't change anything. About the data directory, I did not yet make it external, as I am not sure, which parts of the configuration files I can separate from the internal geonetwork webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I hit this issue the specific schema mentioned was readable by `tomcat` but a dispairing `chown -R tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork` solved the problem. I think it is caused by running as `root` for debugging purposes.